# Error occurred while trying to proxy request issue when configuring proxy for api call in angular6

Tags: angular6

I am new to angular 6 and trying to do api calls with the help of proxy from the following link.

[angular 6 proxy configuration for api call](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1MUmTjYKH8&index=13&list=PLYxzS__5yYQlqCmHqDyW3yo5V79C7eaTe)

but I failed to get response from the server and it shows following error in terminal

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/file2.php from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:1234 (ECONNREFUSED (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

interface myData{
    obj:Object;
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RecordsService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 
    this.recordFunc();
  }
  recordFunc() {

    let headers=new HttpHeaders();
    return this.http.get<myData>('/api/file2.php');
  }
}
```

**proxyconfig.json**

```
 {
    "/api":{
            "target":"http://localhost:1234",
            "secure":false,
            "changeOrigin":true
        }
}
```

I can't understand what the issue is here.I followed the instructions as per in the video.